# Error on code: Sends emails to supposedly non-recipients

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a code that sends an email to different recipients based on a google sheet. However, the code keeps on sending emails to the "owner" recipient, which I hope to stop. To explain further, please see below details.

Here's where people put in their email addresses, tasks, etc.:

[image]

These data are then processed in a hidden sheet that uses several array functions to consolidate tasks for similar emails:

[image]

Now, I'm currently using this code, which perfectly works, except for one flaw:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var now = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var startRow = 2;  
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName ('Tasks')
  var numRows = sheet.getRange("H1").getValue();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, sheet.getLastColumn());
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0]; 
    var message = row[1];
    message = message.replace(/\n/g, "</li><li>");
    var ReminderDate = row[2].toLocaleDateString();
    var Status = row[4];
    var subject = "Task reminders";

    if (ReminderDate > now)
      continue;

    if (Status == 1) {  
      var Email = {
        to: emailAddress,
        subject: "Task reminders  |  "+now,
        htmlBody:
        "Good day! This is to remind you of the following specific task/s:"+
        "<br />"+
        "<ul><li>"+message+"</li></ul>"+
        "<br />"+
        "You can access the Task monitoring sheet by clicking <a href=" + ss.getUrl() + ">here</a>.",
        name: "Taks monitoring",
      };
      MailApp.sendEmail(Email);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 4).setValue(now);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      }
     }
    }
```

And here's what is happening:

- Tasks for email2 are sent to email2 (Yes!)
- Tasks for email1 and email2 are sent to email1 (Oh no!)

I don't like the second bullet from happening, since I only want what's email1 to be sent to email1. I've analyzed the code step-by-step, but I'm not really sure what's wrong in here as to why it keeps doing the second bullet. I tried entering a new email3, and the code also sends email3's tasks to email1.

Any ideas on why this is happening, and suggestions to prevent it?

**Just to note:** `email1` owns the google sheet *(I think it has something to do with that)*.

Comment: Have you check console.log emailAddress and show correct email?

Comment: I would try replacing `email1` with `email4` and then see if the tasks formerly set for `email1` (which should now all go to `email4` and not to `email1`) still end up in the `email1` inbox.

Comment: Is it possible that you are getting data (i.e.- dataRange.getValues()) from the wrong worksheet ?  In other words, is your "for...loop" (data.length) happening 5 times or 2 ?

Comment: Hi @ADW, I tried out your suggestion, and the file still sends the tasks to `email1`, even if all tasks are assigned to `email4`. It's pretty weird. Hmmm. Hoping for your suggestion on what could be done here. Is it because the file is made with `email1` account?

Comment: Hi @AleisterTanekJavasMraz, I'm not sure that's the case since I have the `var sheet = ss.getSheetByName ('Tasks')` part of the code, which directs everything to Tasks sheet. I tried out @ADW's suggestion to test it out, and it seems even when nothing is assigned to `email1`, it still sends out tasks to that email.

Comment: Could it be that you have another `sendEmails()` function in the same project but with the recipient hardcoded to `email1`?

Comment: Hi @ADW, I only have the code above though. So it's not probable that email1 is receiving other tasks because the file was made by that account, correct?

Comment: No, it can't be because email1 created the file. How do you trigger the script? If you can share a link to this file (or of a copy with sensitive information removed) I can take a look and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: @J.Mapz Would you please share your spreadsheet (excluding any private or confidential information)?

Comment: @Tedinoz and ADW apologies for the delayed response. You may check here for a sample copy of the said file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Tb3DLHpAGdDUVlgTmgrR-AmErmJCVVr703kpQtEDSXY/edit?usp=sharing . By the way, when I changed ownership of the file from email1 to email2, and then ran the code, it seemed to be working well (meaning email2 didn't receive any notifications that isn't his). Weird.

Comment: @ADW, apologies for the delayed response. I just pasted the link above. By the way, when I changed ownership of the file from email1 to email2, and then ran the code, it seemed to be working well (meaning email2 didn't receive any notifications that isn't his). Weird.

Comment: I tested your code and it worked fine for me. In my case email1 was also the owner of the spreadsheet. Do you still face this issue?

Comment: @Jescanellas, when I transferred ownership from email1 to email2, and then tested the code, it seemed to be working perfectly fine. That's what is bugging me. When I do it with email1 as owner of the file, it does the error mentioned here. Hmmm.